# Having [suggestions] as a synonym of [discussion] doesn't make sense

Tags: discussion, meta, synonym-request

Here on MSE, [suggestions](/questions/tagged/suggestions) is a synonym of [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion). What? When i think of suggestions, the first thing i think of is going to be [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Wouldn't that be a more appropriate mapping?

Comment: A feature request seems like a much more commited action than a mere suggestion, it's a "request" afterall and not just a debatable suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

That might make sense to you now, but when the synonym was created back in November 2011, all of the use cases pointed to posts with the **suggestions** tag being those that were just discussions, and not for feature requests as such.